# IE select not appending options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a currency converter object and it works great except in IE. None of options get appended to the select element. I have been trying to find a solution for hours but can't figure out what is going on. I am new to javascript so I may be doing something completely wrong just not sure what. It seems like the render method is not getting called from within fetch. Thanks

```
var CurrencyConverter = {

  // Initialize Currency Converter
  // total: jQuery wrapped object that contains the price to convert
  // select: jQuery wrapped select element to render the options tag in
  init: function  (total, select) {

    var that = this;

    this.total = total;
    this.base_price = accounting.unformat(this.total.text());
    this.select = select;

    this.fetch();

    select.change(function () {
      var converted = '',
          formated = '';

      fx.settings = { from: fx.base, to: this.value };
      converted = fx.convert(that.base_price);
      formated = accounting.formatMoney(converted, { symbol: this.value,  format: "%s %v", precision: "0" });

      $(that.total).text(formated);
    });
  },


  // Render Currency Options
  render: function () {

    var that = this,
        accumulator = [],
        frag = '';

    for (var propertyName in fx.rates) {
      accumulator.push(propertyName);
    }

    $.each(accumulator, function ( i, val ) {
      var the_price = $(document.createElement('option')).text(val);

      if (val == fx.base) {
        the_price.attr('selected', 'true');
      }

      // TODO: not optimal to run append through each iteration
      that.select.append(the_price);
    });

  },

  // Fetch & set conversion rates
  fetch: function () {

    var that = this;

    // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:
    $.getJSON(
        'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
        function(data) {
          fx.rates = data.rates;
          fx.base = data.base;

          that.render();
        }
    );
  }
};

if ($('#currency-select')) {
  CurrencyConverter.init($('#price'), $('#currency-select'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is scope.

```
init: function (total, select) {

    var that = this; // Ok, `that` is `init`...

    this.total = total;
    this.base_price = accounting.unformat(this.total.text());
    this.select = select; // So `init.select = select`...
    .
    .
    .

render : function () {
    var that = this, // Ok, `that` is `render`
    accumulator = [],
    frag = '';
    .
    .
    .
    that.select.append(the_price); // ?????
```

The easiest way to solve this, is to create a constructor function instead of a literal object so you can pass `$select` as an object to which you have access within any method.

```
var CurrencyConverter = function($select){
    this.init = function(){ ... }
    this.render = function() { $select.append('...'); }
    .
    .
    .
};
var currency = new CurrencyConverter($('select'));
```

Comment: I reworked the whole thing and scope was definitely the issue thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ye, i've ran too in this. Don't know if it's the right way to solve this but it works, implying that.select is a jQuery result:

> that.select.get(0).add(the_price.get(0))

[Tutorial about working](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial005.html)